# Binding a variable at time of passing callback

Tags: javascript, binding, callback

How do I bind (or pass a value) to a callback at the time the callback function is passed to the caller?

For instance:

```
function callbackTest() {
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
       setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Iteration number ", i); 
        }.bind(i), i*1000);
    }
}

callbackTest();
```

Results in:

```
$ node callback-with-bind.js
Iteration number  3
Iteration number  3
Iteration number  3
```

I would expect the binding to happen at the time the callback is passed to the caller. But no.

How do I do it?

In my actual application, the caller passes another param to my callback, so I can't simply pass i as a param.

```
function callbackTest() {
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        setTimeout(function(myParam){
            console.log("Iteration number ", i);
        }.bind(i), i*1000);
    }
}

callbackTest();
```

Comment: Bind creates a function from another function where some of the parameters are filled in with specific values. Your function doesn't take any parameters so using bind doesn't make any sense

Comment: Your approach doesn't need that binding, just use a IIFE to pass the variable `i`

Comment: @charlietfl, so you say. Though I was unable to find an earlier answer. Link?

Comment: Huh? not sure what you are asking. If looking for the duplicate link it's at top of page as placed by the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind`, when provided a single parameter, sets the function's `this` - in your example, the `i` inside the function is not being bound or altered at all - it's still just using the (global) `i`. You should use `bind`'s *second* parameter, which assigns to the function's first argument, and give your function an appropriate first argument so that it can be used:

```js
function callbackTest() {
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
       setTimeout(function(internalI){
            console.log("Iteration number ", internalI); 
        }.bind(null, i), i*1000);
    }
}

callbackTest();
```

You *could* also use no arguments at all and continue using `bind(i)`, but then you would have to replace `i` with `this` inside your function, which generally isn't the sort of thing that a `this` should refer to:

```js
function callbackTest() {
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
       setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Iteration number " + this); 
        }.bind(i), i*1000);
    }
}

callbackTest();
```

Or, you can just declare `i` with `let`, which has block scope, not global scope or function scope:

```js
function callbackTest() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Iteration number ", i);
    }, i * 1000);
  }
}

callbackTest();
```

Comment: Or he could use `this` inside the function instead of `i`.

Comment: In this example, what's the point of binding ```i``` at all?

Comment: Binding is totally unnecessary, instead, an IIFE passing the variable `i` and returning a function is more suitable.

Comment: Also, in my actual application, the caller passes its own param and I can't pass internalI

Comment: See my edit above about a param.

Comment: Any caveats to let? What is preferred? IIFE or Let?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, want to provide an IIFE example?

Comment: @WesModes `let` (or `const`) is *definitely* the preferable method, since it's clearest and easiest - if you need to support ancient browsers, just Babel first. (Babel is probably part of your build process already if you're developing something semi-professionally) Another good option is to avoid `for` loops entirely use an array method instead, which will give you function scope automatically.